# speeding up refresh for GWT projects

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt2

I'm developing a project, using GWT.FireFox Browser and Eclipse IDE.

when the project is running and i refresh my browser for client package changes, it takes too long. maybe 6 to 10 seconds.

maybe cause be project became big.
how can i speed-up the refresh process on the browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](http://blog.orange11.nl/2007/11/30/optimizing-startup-time-for-gwt-hosted-mode/) might help you.

EDIT: Link now working again.

Comment: The link has broken. Unfortunately this blog no longer exists. [Here](http://blog.orange11.nl/2007/11/30/optimizing-startup-time-for-gwt-hosted-mode/)'s the working link to this article.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there's not a lot you can do to speed up Development Mode refresh time, 6-10 seconds isn't a terrible amount of time comparatively (especially vs. not using Dev Mode and doing a full recompile each time).

If you haven't tried [code splitting](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html) yet, you will almost definitely see a decrease in recompile time, and a decrease in page load time in general once your app is deployed. But beyond that I can't really think of anything that would drastically reduce your Dev Mode refresh time.

Comment: +1 for Code splitting. In addition to splitting, one can try reducing the number of RPC calls at startup. This generally goes unnoticed, specially as the project grows. Some amount of code/RPC profiling should help.